# Create Expression<Func<T,K>> in .Net Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, mapping, runtime

there exists a nice database called LiteDB. What I find inconvenient is an absence of attributes for specifying the relation type (value/reference) between entities, though LiteDB provides fluent interface for hardcoding it (details: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/wiki/DbRef). I am lazy guy and don't want always update this hardcoded relations to follow the changes in my data model. So I decided to realize the runtime discovery of the data model entities with the properties attributed by DbRef (my custom attribute). Unfortunately, I am stuck a little with creating the

```
Expression<Func<T,K>>
```

in the .Net runtime... for providing it in the following call (first parameter):

```
BsonMapper.Global.Entity<Order>().DbRef(x => x.Customer, "customers");
```

Types T and K are given in runtime as instances of System.Type (here in example: T - Order, K - Customer).

I'll really appreciate if you guys give me some hints on how to instantiate

```
Expression<Func<T,K>>
```

in .Net runtime in order to provide it to ...DbRef(...) function.

Comment: Do we have the property name (e.g. `Customer`)?

Comment: Yes, we have property name.

Comment: Why the question is downvoted :( ? Is it too vague?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have the entity type `T`, property type `K` and the property name. To build the `Expression<Func<T, K>>` you could simply use [`Expression.Parameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355908(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Expression.Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341554(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Expression.Lambda`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336566(v=vs.110).aspx) methods like this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var body = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
var selector = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
```

Comment: Dear Ivan, thanks a lot, your solution has resolved the issue!

Comment: Just for completeness, the "<T,K>" might simply be omitted.

Comment: But then the result will be just `LambdaExpression`. I made a mistake thought, in order to get `Expression<Func<T, K>>` it should really be `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, K>>(...)`. Thanks for the note!

Comment: That is the point, I have to instantiate generic type such that T and K are NOT known in the code, but it is available in run-time as the instances of Type. So, my case is handled exactly by this code line `...Expression.Lambda(body, parameter)`. Please, make it be just `...Expression.Lambda(body, parameter)`, then the answer fits the question :)

Comment: @Evgeny Ah, sure, no problem - I was just basing my assumptions of the post title (`Expression<Func<T,K>>`) :)

Answer (score -1):

From you question. Let me send a screenshot to you maybe it can give you a clue[Expression>  Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDSEb.png)

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Fetch(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>  predicate, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>,
        IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy =null, int? page = null, int? pageSize = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }
        if (predicate != null)
        {
            query = query.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
        }
        if (page != null && pageSize != null)
        {
            query = query.Skip((page.Value - 1) * pageSize.Value).Take(pageSize.Value);
        }
        return query;
    }
```

I hope this will help