# Rewrite the type of an Expression<T>

Tags: c#, lambda

Is it possible to dynamically rewrite an `Expression<T>`, replacing an element of `T` with another type?

For example, replacing the `DocumentTypeA` with `DocumentTypeB` in the following situations:

> - `Expression<Func<DocumentTypeA, bool>> expression = m => m.Details.Id == "an-id"`
> - `Expression<Func<DocumentTypeA, bool>> expression = m => m.Details.Id == "an-id" && m.AnInt == 42`
> - `Expression<Func<DocumentTypeA, bool>> expression = m => m.AString == "I'm a string"`

I'll need to make the decision about what type to use at runtime, rather than compile time.

It's also worth noting that `DocumentTypeA` and `DocumentTypeB` don't relate to each other, apart from their properties are identical.

The end result would be to reprocess them so they now look like

> - `Expression<Func<DocumentTypeB, bool>> expression = m => m.Details.Id == "an-id"`
> - `Expression<Func<DocumentTypeB, bool>> expression = m => m.Details.Id == "an-id" && m.AnInt == 42`
> - `Expression<Func<DocumentTypeB, bool>> expression = m => m.AString == "I'm a string"`

So the actual comparison part of the expression remains unchanged, only the top-level type has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Expression<Func<T,K>> in .Net Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026262/create-expressionfunct-k-in-net-runtime)

Comment: If you could, how do you intend to store it? E.g. what's the variable declaration for the *result* going to look like?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've updated it with an example of the desired result. Cheers!

Comment: So you're saying you *do* know the type at compile time, to be able to declare those variables?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No, unfortunately not. I need to be able to account for the change at runtime.

Comment: Then, again, how do you plan to *store the result* of this transformation?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever To keep the question succinct, I didn't mention it. The reason is it's going to an upstream service. The storage, even the execution, is not a concern - only type translation - which is why it's not in the question at all..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ExpressionVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.7.2) to replace the type.

```
class ParameterRewriter<T, U> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Type.Equals(typeof(T)))
        {
            return Expression.Parameter(typeof(U), node.Name);
        }

        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression is ParameterExpression paramExp && paramExp.Type.Equals(typeof(T)))
        {
            return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                Expression.Parameter(typeof(U), paramExp.Name),
                typeof(U).GetMember(node.Member.Name).Single());
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<L>(Expression<L> node)
    {
        var parameters = node.Parameters.ToList();
        var found = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
        {
            if (parameters[i].Type.Equals(typeof(T)))
            {
                parameters[i] = Expression.Parameter(typeof(U), parameters[i].Name);
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (found)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda(node.Body, parameters);
        }

        return base.VisitLambda(node);
    }
}
```

In this case, create an instance `new ParameterRewriter<DocumentTypeA, DocumentTypeB>()` and visit the original expression tree, you will get what you want. An extension method maybe more readable:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<U, R>> RewriteParameter<T, U, R>(this Expression<Func<T, R>> expression)
    {
        var rewriter = new ParameterRewriter<T, U>();
        return (Expression<Func<U, R>>)rewriter.Visit(expression);
    }
}
```

The usage is simple:

```
Expression<Func<A, bool>> expA = x => x.Id == 1;
Expression<Func<B, bool>> expB = expA.RewriteParameter<A, B, bool>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an interface that both classes inherit from and contains the properties that are identical in both of the classes e.g.

```
interface IDocumentTypes
{
    string AString { get; set; } //indicates that both classes need to implement this
    //etc...
}

class DocumentTypeA : IDocumentTypes
{
    //your class
}
```

Then both of your classes can use the `Expression` when it implements the interface `IDocumentTypes` and still be strongly typed. The classes don't need to have anything in common other than implementing the properties/functions defined in the interface.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I can't modify the classes. They're not mine.

Comment: If you have control over creating the objects you could create your own class that uses `DocumentTypeA` as base and the interface e.g. `public class MyDocumentTypeA : DocumentTypeA, IDocumentTypes { }` and use those.